# Increase height and width for frameset

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a frameset in my website. Below is the code:

```
<frameset>
  <frame src="http://www.yiiframework.com/index.php">
</frameset>
```

When i try to view it in PC, it looks perfectly fine. But my website is targeted for mobile phones.

Therefore, I was hoping if there is any way to increase the size. The scroll bars on the right and left would not matter.

I have also tried,

```
<frameset cols="125%" rows="125%">
  <frame src="http://www.yiiframework.com/index.php">
</frameset>
```

But it seems it will be only 100% all the time.

Let me know if there is any possible way to achieve this.